# How to use equals() and contains() to check nullable type of data? I suppose they are both string's methods, but why they behave differently?

Tags: kotlin, null, nullsafe

CASE 1: it can compile and run. why no exception when null call equals() ?

```
var myStr:String? = null
if (myStr.equals("hello"))  
    println("equals hello")
else
    println("not equals hello")
```

CASE 2: it cannot compile. I suppose it is similar to the above case, but I am wrong. Why?

```
var myStr:String? = null
if (myStr.contains("hello"))
    println("contains hello")
else
    println("not contains hello")
```

Comment: Does any of the answers answer your question? If so, please consider accepting one of them by clicking on the checkmark :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`equals` function is defined as extension function on nullable String reference `String?`, while `contains` method is defined on non-nullable `CharSequence`.

```
public actual fun String?.equals(other: String?, ignoreCase: Boolean = false): Boolean = ...


public operator fun CharSequence.contains(other: CharSequence, ignoreCase: Boolean = false): Boolean = ...
```

In both cases `myStr` is nullable String, so you cannot call `contains` directly. You can use null safety operator `?.` for calling `contains`

```
if(myStr?.contains("hello") == true)
    println("contains hello")
else
    println("not contains hello")
```

PS: In case of equality check, you don't need to use `equals` method, instead you can just use `==` operator

Answer (score 2):

`equals` on a nullable string works, only because it is a very special case. There is an [`equals`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/equals.html#equals) specifically written for `String?`.

```
fun String?.equals(
    other: String?, 
    ignoreCase: Boolean = false
): Boolean
```

This wouldn't work on `Int?`, for example:

```
var i: Int? = null
if (i.equals(1)) // error here
    println("equals 1")
else
    println("not equals 1")
```

The `equals` function is declared for `Any`, not `Any?`, so you can't call it on nullable types *in general*.

Anyway, the idiomatic way to compare equality is to use `a == b`, which translates to `a?.equals(b) ?: (b === null)` for a nullable `a`.

There is also no reason to allow `myStr.contains("hello")` to compile, since [`contains`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/contains.html#contains) is declared on the non-nullable `CharSequence`.

```
operator fun CharSequence.contains(
    other: CharSequence, 
    ignoreCase: Boolean = false
): Boolean
```

You can check it like this instead, with nullable chaining:

```
if (myStr?.contains("hello") == true)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the first example, `myStr.equals` calls the [`String?.equals`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/equals.html) extension function, which does the following:

```
if (this === null)
    return other === null
```

In your case, `this` is `null`, and `other` is not `null`, so `other === null` produces `false`.

---

In the second example, `myStr.contains("hello")` is trying to call a function called `contains`, but it doesn't exist, because you have a nullable `String?`, and there is no `contains` function defined for that type. There is the [`CharSequence.contains`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/contains.html) function, but that is only defined for non-nullable types.

So because the function doesn't exist, you get a compiler error.

---

Generally, you don't need to use the `equals` function anyway, and should prefer the `==` operator:

```
val myStr:String? = null
if (myStr == "hello")
    println("equals hello")
else
    println("not equals hello")
```

For contains, you can use the `?.` operator to ensure the object on the left is not null first:

```
val myStr:String? = null
if (myStr?.contains("hello") == true)
    println("contains hello")
else
    println("not contains hello")
```

Here, `myStr?.contains("hello")` produces `null`, and `null == true` is `false`, so the result is `false`.

Comment: So actually, neither of them are using `String`'s methods. 